# Wrapped phase and phase unwrapping in vital sign detection

Tags: phase, radar

I am quite new to the world of radar signal processing and there is this issue that I can't figure out for the life of me.

In [Remote Monitoring of Human Vital Signs Using mm-Wave FMCW Radar](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=8695699,) (Section II.B) it is said that

> "After DC compensation, the phase of each column in the range-slow time matrix is calculated by using $tan^{−1}$ so that the output phases are wrapped in $\left[−\pi, \pi \right]$. In contrast, the phase can change beyond of $\pm \pi$ because $x \left( t \right)$, the physical displacement, can be greater than $\frac{\lambda_{max}}{4}$ (see (5))."

Question 1. Why does phase end up in the range $\left[- \pi, \pi \right]$ (The $\mathbf{arctan}$ function has a range of $\left[- \frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2} \right]$ so I initially thought the extracted phase would equally fall in this interval)

Question 2. How do we conclude from equation 5:
$$4 \pi \cfrac{R_{0} + x \left( t_{0} \right)}{\lambda_{max}}$$

that the phase difference between two consecutive samples has to exceed $\pi$?

Comment: I'm also quite new to world of radar signal processing. I don't understand why we have to make phase unwrapping process. Could you light in me about it? It would be nice conversation speak about it. I would appreciate if you share useful resources, I am stuck on this. I have read 4-5 articles about detection of human vital signs but Phase unwrapping process was not clearly stated in any of them. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> Question 1. How does it happen that the phase ends up in the range $\left[- \pi, \pi \right]$

You don't apply $\tan^{-1}$ blindly but use the sign of the imaginary parts to determine the correct quadrant. Almost all programming languages have a variant of `atan()` and it's called `atan2()`. In most formulas it's implied that you use the "correct quadrant" of the $\tan^{-1}$. Good reading on the topic  [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20polar%20coordinate,angle%20from%20a%20reference%20direction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20polar%20coordinate,angle%20from%20a%20reference%20direction).

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out that subtility. It was a little bit naive of me. so atan2 effectively considers the sign relation between both the real and imaginary parts in order to resolve all 4 quadrants